# JS string invert match (RegEx)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string and I want to divide the parts that match a regex from rest of the text.

```
var str = 'Lorem ipsum [asdasd]dolor si[@@]c amet';
var brackets = str.match(/\[[\s\S]+\]);  // ['[asdasd]', '[@@]']
var lipsum = ???                         // ['Lorem ipsum ', 'dolor si', 'c amet']
```

Is there any way to do this natively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using match, you can use split with a pattern matching from `[...]` in a capture group and get all the matches in one array.

```js
var str = 'Lorem ipsum [asdasd]dolor si[@@]c amet';
console.log(str.split(/(\[[^\][]*])/));
```

If you want separate matches for the bracket and lipsum, you might use the same pattern with for example reduce:

```js
const str = '[Lorem ipsum [asdasd]dolor si[@@]c amet';
const res = str
    .split(/(\[[^\][]*])/)
    .reduce((a, c) => {
    /^\[[^\][]*]$/.test(c) ? a.brackets.push(c) : a.lipsum.push(c); return a;
}, {brackets:[], lipsum:[]})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

`[\s\S]` will match everything, because `\s` matches any whitespace character and `\S` matches any non-whitespace character. You can thus use `.` instead.

```js
let text = 'Lorem ipsum [asdasd]dolor si[@@]c amet';

let brackets = text.match(/\[.+?\]/g);
console.log(brackets)
```

As pointed out by [@The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird), using a negated character class is way faster ! You should thus use `/\[[^\][]*]/g` instead.

---

In order to match the other part, **splitting** the string is not a reliable solution: if the `[...]` are at start or end of the string, it will create empty strings.

Here is one way to do so using `match()` instead:

```js
let text = 'Lorem ipsum [asdasd]dolor si[@@]c amet';

let lipsum = text.match(/(?<=\]|^)[^[\]]+(?=\[|$)/g);
console.log(lipsum)
```

The regex used is the following:

```
(?<=\]|^)[^[\]]+(?=\[|$)
```

- `(?<=)`: Positive lookbehind.

  - `\]`: Matches `]`.
  - `|`: Or.
  - `^`: Start of the string.
- `[^[\]]+`: Matches any character other than `[` and `]`, between one and unlimited times, as much as possible.
- `(?=)`: Positive lookahead.

  - `\[`: Matches `[`.
  - `|`: Or.
  - `$`: End of the string.

Instead of matching the parts enclosed in `[...]`, we match the parts enclosed in `]...[`. Using lookarounds allows square brackets to not be included.